# Sending java.lang.Boolean over JSON (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, boolean

I have a bean with an Boolean (not primitive boolean) attribute. This is because the attribute isn't relevant for every instance of this class, hence should be `nullable`.

Bean is sent as a JSON on a create REST service. The controller receives `null` instead of the actual value.

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myBean")
public class MyBeanController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBeanService myBeanService;

    @PostMapping("/create" )
    public ResponseEntity createTransaction(@RequestBody MyBeanDTO myBean) {
        MyBeanDTO result = myBeanService.create(myBean);
        return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My bean:

```
public class MyBean  {

    . . .
    private Boolean active;
    . . .

    public Boolean getActive() { //Instead of isActive, as it's Boolean and not boolean
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

None of the JSON I send parses the attribute "active" correctly, and always comes as `null`. I've tried true, "true", { "value" : true}. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [@JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to field :

```
@JsonProperty("active")
private Boolean active
```

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized, deserialized) as a logical property.

If it doesn't work remove `@RequestBody` before `MyBeanDTO`  in  `createTransaction` method

Comment: @JsonProperty solved my problem by using "active" : true in the JSON. Thank you very much!